# Creating a timeline in Python or R from a CSV file

Tags: python, r, csv, plot, timeline

I have a CSV file that contains two columns. The first column is dates in a `%m/%d/%y` format, and the second column is combination of alphanumeric characters that are lower/upper case. Sometimes there might be >1 hostname per date, in which case they're separated by a coma, and also sometimes a hostname might contain a special character like a hyphen or a period.

I'd also mention that this is file is depicting the day a host was disabled from a network.

Here is a sample:

```
6/7/17  ml12308sASd
8/28/17 Mloasjdiaosjd1028knsd, mlsaj19209s, asd12122sda
8/28/17 Amandas-macbook.local
9/13/18 john-deers_win.local
```

I am trying to create a timeline showing that on X day XYZ host was disabled.

Here is my basic R script to depict the data type that R reads my csv file as:

```
df <-read.csv("users_per_date.csv")
colnames(df) <- c("Start","Host")

x <- typeof(df)
print(x)
[1] "list"
```

Any help in R or Python would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the structure of the data once it is imported into R?

Comment: The structure of data once it is imported is a list.

Comment: A problem I see is that you are reading in a csv, while separating variables that are supposed to exist in the same group with a comma, which will be separated during the `read.csv`. Therefore you will get a list `[1] 6/7/17  [2] ml12308sASd
[3] 8/28/17 [4] Mloasjdiaosjd1028knsd [5] mlsaj19209s [6] asd12122sda [7] 8/28/17` which complicates things. You will have to figure out how to get this into a structured data frame, like the one you showed in the sample, before aggregating.

Comment: I can use bash to parse this out as necessary...perhaps the following?

`cat users_per_date.csv | sed 's/,/ /g' > text.txt` This will substitute all commas with whitespace and convert to a text file. Would this normalize the datatypes you imagine?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get your list into a structured df, assuming the read.csv reads everything into a list structured similar to mine. If your data is already in a structure similar to the one depicted in the sample, see the last part of this answer.

**Data Cleaning and Structuring from type list:**

```
library(stringr)

#Loaded CSV Data in list
list1<-list(
"6/7/17", "ml12308sASd",
"8/28/17","Mloasjdiaosjd1028knsd", 
"mlsaj19209s", "asd12122sda",
"8/28/17","Amandas-macbook.local",
"9/13/18", "john-deers_win.local"
)

list2<-unlist(list1)

#Collapse to one string
list3<-paste(list2, collapse=' ')

#Find groups for users
users<-regmatches(list3,gregexpr("(?<=\\d\\/..\\s)(.*?)(?=(..\\/..\\/)|($))",list3, perl=T))

#Unlist to index
users<-unlist(users)

#Split individual users per group
users<-strsplit(users, "\\s+")

#Concatenate group individuals, separated with comma
for(i in 1:length(users)){
users[i]<-str_c(users[[i]], sep="", collapse=", ")
}

#Re-unlist as concatenate lsited
users<-unlist(users)

#Grab dates from main string
dates<-regmatches(list3,gregexpr("(..|.)\\/(..|.)\\/..",list3, perl=T))

#Unlist Dates
dates<-unlist(dates)

#Put into data frame
df<-data.frame(dates,users)

> df
     dates                                         users
1   6/7/17                                   ml12308sASd
2  8/28/17 Mloasjdiaosjd1028knsd, mlsaj19209s, asd12122sda
3  8/28/17                         Amandas-macbook.local
4  9/13/18                          john-deers_win.local
```

**Aggregate based on Date**

```
#Ensure dates are correct class for aggregation
df$dates<-as.POSIXct(df$dates, format="%m/%d/%y")

#Aggregate based on date, paste used as function
Data_Fin <- aggregate(x = df["users"],
                      FUN=paste,
                     by = df["dates"])

> Data_Fin
       dates  users
1 2017-06-07  ml12308sASd
2 2017-08-28  Mloasjdiaosjd1028knsd, mlsaj19209s, asd12122sda, Amandas-macbook.local
3 2018-09-13  john-deers_win.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but you can easily read the table using pandas. By the option parse dates the dates in the list get formatted as index and entries are sorted to it.

As in comments said as more hosts u have in the list you get a second, third, ... column which can be searched.

Going through the list u can easily get the hosts you are searching and save them in proper reformatted way